# Use Angular Observable or Event Emitters for "plain" objects"?

Tags: angular, observable

I'm trying to get my head around modern Angular, and hours of Googling for, whatever reason, aren't leading to clarity (it may be that I skipped lunch). I'm trying to prototype a file upload widget to get started.

Here's what I have so far:

- "File- a simple class with a few properties, some of which are stateful (ex. upload status)
- "FileComponent" - a component to render a File
- "FileListComponent" - a component that includes a property that's an array of Files

I need to be able to do the following:

1. Instantiate new File objects when a user does a drag & drop on the FileListComponent
2. Update the status of the File object as it uploads
3. Have the FileComponent's view refresh when its corresponding File's state changes

FileListComponent's template looks something like this:

```
<div class="file-list">
    <file-comp *ngFor="let file of files" [file]="file"></file-comp>
<div>
```

FileComponent's template looks like this:

```
<div class="file">
    <div>{{ file.filename }}</div>
    <div>{{ file.status }}</div>
<div>
```

I can add new Files, they show up in the FileListComponent, rendered using FileComponent.  So far so good...

This is where I'm stuck...

As "file.status" changes, I would like the FileComponent to update.

It sound like I want to leverage Observables, but most examples I've read show AJAX examples of objects being returned from calls, and not so much about how to make individual properties of a class Observable.  Also, most examples show data properties as part of the component class itself, as opposed to a separate object.

Does anybody know of an example where I can wire up a simple object to a Component, and have changes to properties of that object reflect in the component's rendering?

Comment: Options to consider: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EventEmitter** is built based on Subject, which is Observable and Observer.
**Subject** mainly used to send signals, and can't hold values.

There are few other objects like Subject like: 

**BehaviorSubject** - Similar to Subject, But can hold one last value persistent, so every subscriber can access to the last emitted value.

**ReplaySubject** - Similar to BehaviorSubject, but can hold multiple emitted values, based on the initialization of the object.

In you case, I would suggest to use something like BehaviorSubject, so you may hold the current progression. 
You can share data between parent and child components simply by using something like:

**Parent:**

```
<child-component 
  data="someObjectFromParnet" (somethingChange)="changeFunc($event)">
</child-component>
```

And in code:

```
changeFunc = (event) => {
 console.log(event);
}
```

**Child:**

```
@Input() data;
@Output() somethingChange = new EventEmitter();

constructor(){
 console.log(data); // <-- data sent from parent.
 this.somethingChange.emit(`sending back data to parent${data}`);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the concise, well documented example.  EventEmitter in my model did the trick for me.  In my Component, I set changeDetection to OnPush, and used changeDetectorRef.detectChanges() to trigger the UI updates.